# NodeJS setInterval() running parallel to loop using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have two functions

1. `console.log()` running every second, using `setInterval()`
2. a constant loop calculating (eg. repeatedly calculating sha256)

Using asynchronous JavaScript, how can I run both a constant loop and still `console.log()` every second.

Everything I've tried brought no solution, as the calculating loop always goes to the top of JavaScript's queue and runs until it I manually stop this loop and then the interval starts going every second

I know that a solution also involves Web Workers, but I would rather like to understand this first.

Comment: In short: The JS engine is too busy running your loop to go and look at the queue of tasks being generated by setInterval.

Comment: TL;DR: Only one thing can happen at a time. If a loop is blocking the thread, then no `console.log` can squeeze in between that.